# How to generate quality WAVE file using Java

Tags: java, wav, javasound

I am trying to generate a quality `WAVE` file using the Java Sound API.

First I used the following values with `8kHz` sample rate. And the quality is `128kbps`. But it is not generating quality audio. Some words are even not clearly pronounced.

```
static AudioFormat.Encoding defaultEncoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
static float fDefaultSampleRate = 8000;
static int nDefaultSampleSizeInBits = 16;
static int nDefaultChannels = 1;
static int frameSize = 2;
static float frameRate = 8000;
static boolean bDefaultBigEndian = false;

AudioFormat defaultFormat = new AudioFormat(defaultEncoding, fDefaultSampleRate, nDefaultSampleSizeInBits, nDefaultChannels, frameSize, frameRate, bDefaultBigEndian);
AudioInputStream GeneratedAudio = marytts.generateAudio(text); //generate audio from text
AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultFormat, GeneratedAudio);
AudioSystem.write(audio, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("FileName.wav"));
```

So then I used the following values with `44.1kHz` sample rate. Also showing the quality as `705kbps` But the problem is when I generate audio with these values the generated audio is quality but there are some noises like cracking when playing the audio.

```
static AudioFormat.Encoding defaultEncoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
static float fDefaultSampleRate = 44100;
static int nDefaultSampleSizeInBits = 16;
static int nDefaultChannels = 1;
static int frameSize = 2;
static float frameRate = 44100;
static boolean bDefaultBigEndian = false;

AudioFormat defaultFormat = new AudioFormat(defaultEncoding, fDefaultSampleRate, nDefaultSampleSizeInBits, nDefaultChannels, frameSize, frameRate, bDefaultBigEndian);
AudioInputStream GeneratedAudio = marytts.generateAudio(text); //generate audio from text
AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultFormat, GeneratedAudio);
AudioSystem.write(audio, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("FileName.wav"));
```

So what I need to know is how can I generate quality audio without having some cracking background noises using this `Java sound` API? I am very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are just showing an `AudioFormat` and not any code that truly *generates* audio. How do you generate your audio? If you are using a microphone, most likely that's the problem.

Comment: Actually I am building a Text To Speech application using `MaryTTS`. I have updated the code. But that noise is not in the `8kHz`generated audio. Also `8kHz` is showing as `128kbps` and `44.1kHz` is showing as `705kbps`.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(GeneratedAudio.getAudioFormat());` produce? You might be better off, to first dump the stream provided by MaryTTS without transcoding to another audio format, i.e. simply do `AudioSystem.write(GeneratedAudio, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("FileName.wav"));`

Comment: @hendrik I did that. Thank you very much for that idea. When I generate stream provided by the MaryTTS, the values are `256kbps` and `16kHz`. So, there is no crackle and sound quality is also good. But is there any way to make them `44.1 kHz`?

Comment: Your audio won't be any better after upsampling to 44.1kHz, so I don't see a big advantage here. The most reliable way to do it is probably using FFmpeg or SOX on the command line. If you want to do it in Java, make sure that you are *only* changing the samplerate/framerate, but nothing else (so same endianness etc.). That way the task gets a little easier for the transcoder. Perhaps it works. If not, try adding something like http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/ to your project (if it's on macOS or Windows).

Comment: @hendrik Thank you very much for the information you gave. I will check them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could result in crackling: from over-driving the speakers, to overflowing the number of bits to overly large discontinuities in the data.

For 16-bit encoding (standard for "CD Quality audio"), all your PCM data points should lie within the range -32767 to 32767 (fits in a `short`) prior to conversion of the PCM values to bytes.

If they do, then I would look next to make sure I had the byte order correct, and at the algorithm that is producing the PCM values. IDK what to recommend for testing that besides inspection. Maybe try generating a simple sine wave at various volumes and see if the PCM values are as expected, for starters?

16-bit, mono, at 44100 fps should sound pretty good. Any chance what you are describing as crackle might be a form of aliasing? (I don't usually think of that form of distortion as a crackle.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have generated the audio file using stream provided by `MaryTTS` and the values are `256kbps` and `16kHz` now.